# Access NoScript keyboard shortcuts

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, noscript

Which key combination should I press on the keyboard to toggle NoScript? The configuration (about:config) says:

```
noscript.keys.toggle: ctrl shift VK_BACK_SLASH.|
```

Comment: FYI for people coming across this in 2018: the new keyboard shortcut to do things is `alt + shift + n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a combination <kbd>Ctr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> simultaneously. [image]

Answer (score 1):

```
If you're not a mouse lover, you will find these two keyboard shortcuts helpful:

CTRL + SHIFT + \ (backslash) toggles allowance status for the current top-level site - temporarily by default, to make it permanent set the about:config noscript.toggle.temp preference to false.
CTRL + SHIFT + N opens the NoScript status bar menu, which lets you perform every NoScript related operation using the cursor keys.
Both these shortcuts can be changed using the about:config noscript.key.* preferences.
```

it's just like "week" said.

Comment: It is working when I switch to English layout, but not with my default Hungarian one. Backslash is on AltGr + q. ("generic qwertz 101-key" keyboard)

Comment: i think u can define it for yourself. like it said : `Both these shortcuts can be changed using the about:config noscript.key.* preferences.`

Comment: Is there a way to turn of the CTRL + SHIFT + \ short cut? It's driving me crazy, since it blocks all javascript and forces a page refresh every time I accidentally press those buttons, causing me to loose changes.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Noscript 10 in Firefox 57 Quantum, the NoScript menu can be brought up with
<kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd>

The menu can be navigated with <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> arrow keys, and permissions for selected domains changed with <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd>.

The "toggle permissions" action does not currently have a keyboard shortcut assigned to it (see [opened issue](https://github.com/hackademix/noscript/issues/45)).